# bash script: -Xmx16M: command not found

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a common run-class.sh file defined as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$MAIN_CLASS" ] ; then
    echo "Do not run this script on its own. It's intended to be included in other commands."
    exit 1
fi

JAVA_ARGS=-client -Xmx16M
export JAVA_ARGS

DIR=`dirname "$0"`

# set jars
JARS=
for JAR in $DIR/../lib/*.jar; do JARS=$JAR:$JARS; done

# set java classpath and export
CLASSPATH=$DIR/../conf/:$DIR/../conf/*:$JARS
export CLASSPATH

java $JAVA_ARGS $MAIN_CLASS "$@"
```

and another test-class.sh script as follows to invoke a java class:

```
#!/bin/bash
MAIN_CLASS="com.my.package.TestClass"

. run-class.sh
```

When I run the test-class.sh file as follows:

```
>./test-class.sh
```

I get a console message saying:

```
run-class.sh: line 8: -Xmx16M: command not found
```

I'm not sure why this is incorrect when I'm already exporting the JAVA_ARGS.

Comment: Try JAVA_ARGS="-client -Xmx16M"

Answer (score 3):

Use quotes with JAVA_ARGS assignment :

```
JAVA_ARGS="-client -Xmx16M"
```

Answer (score 1):

I find using bash arrays tends to make things more robust:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$MAIN_CLASS" ] ; then
    echo "Do not run this script on its own. It's intended to be included in other commands."
    exit 1
fi

# use an array
java_args=(-client -Xmx16M)

dir=$(dirname "$0")

# set java classpath and export
cp=( 
    "$dir"/../.conf/
    "$dir"/../.conf/"*"     # I assume you want a literal star here
    "$dir"/../lib/*.jar
)
export CLASSPATH=$( IFS=":"; echo "${cp[*]}" )

java "${java_args[@]}" "$MAIN_CLASS" "$@"
```

Other notes:

- don't use ALL_CAPS variable names, except for environment variables.
- read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Robust in what sense?

Comment: Suppose one of your java args contains a space, hypothetically `--foo "bar baz"` -- that is impossible to keep that as a single unit if you use a string to hold the args. Spend some time with that BashFAQ page.

Answer (score 0):

You can set variables that are localized to a command.
Most everyone knows simple environment vars, set like this -

```
$: x=foo
$: echo $x
foo
```

But you can set a local override.

```
$: x=bar eval 'echo $x' # <<--- uses echo's local x
bar
$: echo $x
foo
```

(Just don't be fooled by a false test...

```
$: x=bar echo $x # $x parsed BEFORE passing to echo
foo
```

...which will confuse you if you don't realize echo received the *value* when the line was parsed, so didn't see the change.)

So, by saying

```
JAVA_ARGS=-client -Xmx16M
```

without quotes, the command interpreter is assuming this is what you are doing, and failing because `-Xmx16M` isn't found. By putting quotes around it you make the entire value part of the assignment.

```
JAVA_ARGS='-client -Xmx16M'
```

This will do what you wanted.